# Xamarin - Not able to detect ListView ItemClick event

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to get `ItemClick` in `ListView` but not able to detect. I have tried to implement `ClickListener` in `GetView()` method of `BaseAdapter` as well as I have tried `ItemClick` of `ListView`. I am not getting any kind of success. Here is my snippet.

In this give snippet I have tried to implement `ClickListener` in `GetView()`

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.single_row_listview_item, parent, false);

            ImageView photo = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.photoImageView);
            TextView name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameTextView);
            TextView speciality = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.specialtyTextView);

            Stream stream = context.Assets.Open(places[position].ImageUrl);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.CreateFromStream(stream, null);
            photo.SetImageDrawable(drawable);

            name.Text = places[position].Name;
            speciality.Text = places[position].Specialty;

            name.Click += delegate
            {
                CommonUtils.showToast(context, "Click on name");
            };

            speciality.Click += delegate
            {
                CommonUtils.showToast(context, "Click on speciality");
            };

            photo.Click += delegate
            {
                CommonUtils.showToast(context, "Click on photo");
            };

            view.Click += delegate
            {
                CommonUtils.showToast(context, "Click on view");
            };



            return view;
        }
```

I have tried ItemClick as well and here is a snippet as well.

```
placeList.ItemClick += PlaceList_ItemClick;
private void PlaceList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
       Console.WriteLine("item clicked ");
       CommonUtils.showToast(this,"Item clicked");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm just guessing but is it possible that something in your UI is preventing your items to detect touch event?

Comment: @Yupi I have put listener code in every single view. But not aable to get detected.

Comment: But why are you implementing Click method on each view in your ListView why just not on item of ListView, because in your last posted code you are calling the click on ListView items but you didn't actually implemented it? Or I'm missing something.

Comment: @Yupi The reason why I have implemented click method on each view because I just want to make sure that any of these views might detect this event. But I am done with no success.

Comment: If you are trying to get click on ListView items than you should subscribe to  an event in place where you populate ListView with data:
 `placeList.ItemClick += PlaceList_ItemClick;` than you can call method: 

`void PlaceList_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //Get our item from the list adapter
    var item = this.listAdapter.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);

    //Make a toast with the item name just to show it was clicked
    Toast.MakeText(this, item.Name + " Clicked!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}`

Comment: Nope. No Success mate. @Yupi

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue by my side.  Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes, I have tried each and every step to get it work. I have used this in my DrawerLayout. Am I missing something else ? @GraceFeng-MSFT